# How to parse dynamic array of JSON

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm attempting to parse the FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallLog which has an AdditionalFields column as described below. I thought I could run *mv-expand* and then *evaluate bag_unpack* to parse this column. However, mv-expand has no effect on the **details_matches** column, it simply returns the original input. What I would like it to do is to break each JSON string into a separate row. How to achieve that?

```
datatable(Column: string) [ 
   '{\"socketIP\":\"1.1.1.6\",\"details_matches\":\"[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableName\\\": \\\"CookieValue:search.settings.breadcrumb\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableValue\\\": \\\"[{\\\\\\\"ownerId\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\"folderId\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\"folderName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Saved Settings\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"searchLevel\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"isSubFolderForMcApp\\\\\\\":false},{\\\\\\\"ownerId\\\\\\\":60409,\\\\\\\"folderId\\\\\\\":29193,\\\\\\\"folderName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"My saved settings\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"searchLevel\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"isSubFolderForMcApp\\\\\\\":false}]\\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableName\\\": \\\"CookieValue:user.trail\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableValue\\\": \\\"[{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"pletion\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Completion\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"rojectslixx\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"67\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"913384\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:20:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"}]\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]\",\"details_msg\":\"Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination\"}'
]
| extend Column_d = todynamic(Column)
| extend socketIp_s = Column_d.socketIP
| extend details_msg = Column_d.details_msg
| extend details_matches = Column_d.details_matches
| project socketIp_s, details_matches, details_msg, Column_d
```

edit: Question has now been answered by David. Would still like to know why

```
| extend Column_d = todynamic(Column)
| extend details_matches = Column_d.details_matches
| mv-expand details_matches
```

does not have any effect on the column **details_matches**, while the answer below does. Why is that?

Comment: **(1)** A value extracted from a dynamic field is also dynamic. **(2)** parse_json works on strings. Given a dynamic value as input, it returns that value As Is. **(1) + (2) ==>**  `mv-expand parse_json(tostring(details_matches))`

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(Column: string) [ 
   '{\"socketIP\":\"1.1.1.6\",\"details_matches\":\"[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableName\\\": \\\"CookieValue:search.settings.breadcrumb\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableValue\\\": \\\"[{\\\\\\\"ownerId\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\"folderId\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\"folderName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Saved Settings\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"searchLevel\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"isSubFolderForMcApp\\\\\\\":false},{\\\\\\\"ownerId\\\\\\\":60409,\\\\\\\"folderId\\\\\\\":29193,\\\\\\\"folderName\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"My saved settings\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"searchLevel\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"isSubFolderForMcApp\\\\\\\":false}]\\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableName\\\": \\\"CookieValue:user.trail\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"matchVariableValue\\\": \\\"[{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"pletion\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Completion\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"rojectslixx\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"67\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"},{\\\\\\\"url\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"913384\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"referrer\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Last page\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"time\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Tue Nov 29 2022 08:20:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)\\\\\\\"}]\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]\",\"details_msg\":\"Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination\"}'
]
| extend Column = parse_json(Column)
| evaluate bag_unpack(Column)
| mv-expand parse_json(details_matches)
| evaluate bag_unpack(details_matches)
| mv-expand parse_json(matchVariableValue)
| evaluate bag_unpack(matchVariableValue)
```

| details_msg | socketIP | matchVariableName | folderId | folderName | isSubFolderForMcApp | ownerId | referrer | searchLevel | time | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:search.settings.breadcrumb |  | Saved Settings | false |  |  | 0 |  |  |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:search.settings.breadcrumb | 29193 | My saved settings | false | 60409 |  | 0 |  |  |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:user.trail |  |  |  |  | Last page |  | Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | pletion |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:user.trail |  |  |  |  | Last page |  | Tue Nov 29 2022 07:09:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | Completion |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:user.trail |  |  |  |  | Last page |  | Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | rojectslixx |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:user.trail |  |  |  |  | Last page |  | Tue Nov 29 2022 08:19:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | 67 |
| Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination | 1.1.1.6 | CookieValue:user.trail |  |  |  |  | Last page |  | Tue Nov 29 2022 08:20:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | 913384 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8VVUW/aMBB%20R%20I/nPLSogFLAqNNpD1MbJ0qQbUJ1BeMkJMcNMWxI9thVB3/fU5oKB2wTR1j8cvZd/fdfc75LqLarIDheVewLOE%20KC1jPqvBCKoVADh7JJYS4Rz19Rdi%20cRymvnqEKtOrAg1jZmaJFSHd6gK/YgQSQgHeCwFAEKIVdjcUhnn0W5ogvmhX6i6QsxjvKUsQ18hleFdU6HWJg3VDCTSKJRZEuSW9V9gFv7PoCMTv/gs8Y2jvI7Krc8zxurlbipY9DvtU7ZrfSkM6AIjGDzlWZ5uPNc8erhAtnG1N9pYDbLgqgC/ErIffkjTjdWUMoWr%20sH0O3bb9g7n73qO1/oTAv0HUAUH9a84jHO5/GOr%20t8VRqZQNrU09fbqQsjkM49SSBnqWPAd7hKnKCXKHYceVRpSOsMdFx3vueVhhnAjFuB64NquC/aFb3u%20bcPn/vCN7RjhvIvc8GLwKZMiRcphoCmPqIxgaBBrJdJWSewj0hXJf%20LSPjoXKe4x1IrFy%20XpyFz6jue/c45OpnNxag7e0Tl4Tqt12T4lD9d%20XWG97DlrYfxyWKlZMag%20os6LDPoPg689CEWSmBCNtyqlITZEMM1USLVpjzHPi9G8KwUmIgQ0nOs4nINGmcScFi/OWp1VK%20Nq5TvgUqOxWk9TeG8uQSqc3CvBnyZsrbBamB5l0A3abJJxE3K%20rU4WDVymebQt95%20G7UGcfXZ7AXeb5kHMPaY/AB4l22I6CAAA)

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand the difference between attempting to mv-expand a dynamic value, like I did, and mv-expand a string you run parse_json on. Could you explain?

Comment: I don't know what you've tried. You can add the code to your question and I'll comment.